# Ship Roslyn code refactoring as NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, roslyn

When installing the [.NET Compiler Platform SDK](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2ddb7240-5249-4c8c-969e-5d05823bcb89) you get Visual Studio templates for creating an "Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)" and a "Code Refactoring (VSIX)".

Why isn't there a template for shipping a code refactoring with NuGet (like "Code Refactoring (NuGet + VSIX)")?
Is it even possible to add a code refactoring provider from a NuGet package (by creating the NuGet package manually)?
Doesn't it make sense to install a code refactoring provider on a project per project basis?

EDIT:
My use case is a code refactoring that generates a C# type out of untyped data (like JSON). This is basically what F# type providers are (although they are much more powerful of course). This means that the user creates a class like the following

```
[JsonProvider("http://example.com/data.json")]
public class ExampleData
{
}
```

and the refactoring fills it with properties from the sample data it fetched from the url in the attribute:

```
[JsonProvider("http://example.com/data.json")]
public class ExampleData
{
    public string Property1 { get; private set; }
    public int Property2 { get; private set; }

    public void Load(Uri uri) { ... }
    public void FromData(string data) { ... }
    ...
}
```

The reason I don't want to create an analyzer is because the user should be able to decide when to update the C# type. Because I don't really know when the data the URL points to is changing. And I don't want to annoy the user with a squiggly line that she can't get rid of.

Comment: Can you expand on what your example is? Are you sure that this refactoring that should only apply to some projects isn't in fact an analyzer/code fix in disguise?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thx, I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distributing  refactorings via NuGet is not currently supported, but is something we would like to add in the future.

Comment: I see, thanks. Are there any technical difficulties? Analyzers and Code Refactorings seem quite similar.

Comment: @JohannesEgger: Refactorings are loaded into the IDE as MEF exports, and MEF doesn't allow you to dynamically change the composition graph as you open and close projects (this is why you must restart VS after installing an extension).

Comment: Analyzers, by contrast, are loaded via a special locating system built into Roslyn itself, specifically to avoid this issue (and also because they're used by the core compilers, which are not built on MEF)

Comment: See http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/AnalyzerReference.cs,7

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thanks for that.

Comment: Right, the unfortunate corollary to the fact that they are loaded as MEF exports is that they can MEF *import*, so moving them to be loaded separately could end up being a breaking change (though I suppose we could require you to opt-in to it with a new attribute).