# What is the difference between a Roslyn CodeFix and Refactoring?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have been scouring all possible documentation I could find about the Roslyn APIs but I could not find an answer to this simple question.

I know a CodeFix inherits from CodeFixProvider and provides a Code Fix.
I also know that a Refactoring inherits from CodeRefactoringProvider and provides a Refactoring.
One difference I found is that for some reason you cannot redistribute Refactorings using Nuget, only through a VSIX, while you can redistribute a CodeFix using both.

But what exactly is a Code Fix and what is a Refactoring? What can one do that the other cannot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Code Fix is for where you've identified an *error* or *mistake* in the code and can deduce how to *correct* the code.

A Refactoring is a *change* to the code that usually will make it neither more nor less *correct*. It's not unusual to offer multiple refactorings that will transform the code between various forms, including, often, back to the form it was in before someone accepted any refactoring. In contrast, it would be rare in the extreme to find another Code Fix (in the same package) that transformed code into a form that another Code Fix could apply to.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the conceptual difference. But what is the practical one? What can a Code Refactoring do that a Code Fix can't and vise-versa? Why the technical limitation of being able to redistribute only Code Fixes through Nuget and not Refactorings?

Comment: @Phoenix - I don't think there are any impossible to fix limitations that would have made it impossible to support Refactorings in Nuget. I think in practice though they expect most refactorings to be generic, so it makes sense to install them "globally" rather than on a per-project basis. Whereas at least some Code Fixes will be provided as enhancements to assist people using a specific API, for example.

Comment: @Phoenix - As at 2015 they stated that it wasn't currently possible but they'd [like to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125141/15498). Some interesting points in the comments talking about how MEF may be one of the current limitations.

Comment: It's more about the where and how these items were intended to be used.  Code fixes can be distributed via Nuget because they were designed to be distributed along with your custom components and classes; to provide better IDE support for specific features of your package that VS can't infer on its own.

Comment: @Dami Yes, I went through that answer as well. So you are basically saying that there is not a functional difference between a Code Fix and Refactoring, just a conceptual one? I.e both can do the same, albeit in a slightly different way?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hi, do you know if CodeRefactoringProvider(s) can be shipped by nuget's as CodeFixes and CodeAnalyzers now in 2020? Or is it possible only by VSIX?

Answer (score 1):

The conceptual difference in the accepted answer is also in a way the practical difference.

Both CodeFixProviders and CodeRefactoringProviders generate CodeActions that users can apply to their code. The key difference is that each CodeAction offered by a CodeFixProvider has to be associated with (and is presumed to address) one or more Diagnostics produced by a Roslyn Analyzer, whereas a CodeAction offered by a CodeRefactoringProvider is not associated with any Diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer there is another functional difference between code fix and code refactoring. You can easily add support to solution wide code fix by overriding *GetFixAllProvider*:

```
public override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider() => WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;
```

But as far as I know there isn't such an easy way to provide mass refactoring